# Created HTML file isn't recognized by my device

Tags: java, android, html, file-writing

I create a test html file on an Android (7.0) device from string content. File is created fine, shows up with right extension and icon, but format isn't recognized when tapped, giving message "file format is not supported". Yet, if I save this same file to PC and transfer back to device, the issue disappears. It then shows app choices to open html, as it should be.

Tried several write methods. In all cases file was created and content looked right, but format wasn't recognized rightaway. Can't figure out why, is there an extra step or written data required for this? The latest one was with BufferedWriter (to ensure UTF-8) as below:

```
  final File file = new File(path, name + file_extension);
  StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

  strBuilder.append("test");
  strBuilder.insert(0, "<html>"+"\r\n"+"<body><p>"+"\r\n");
  strBuilder.insert(strBuilder.length(), "\r\n"+"</p></body>"+"\r\n"+ "</html>");

  String html_content=strBuilder.toString();

  try
  {

  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  bw.write(html_content);
  bw.close();

  } catch (IOException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
      Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
  }
```

Comment: Please show complete code. Including the path you use.

Comment: `when tapped`? When, where and how do you tap? And where does it show up,?

Comment: Thanks, added the file part. This is the full code inside a method "createHtml(File path, String name)". File gets created in correct path (currently "/storage/emulated/0", but user can change this). By tapping, I meant in a file explorer app. Shows up there with correct icon and extension. Expecting format to be recognized by OS upon this action, like happens with other html files. This doesn't happen however (unless I transfer file to and from PC, back to device). As if some data is missing in initially created file or related update in file system.

Comment: `Thanks, added the file part. `. ???? I cannot see which path you use. Nor file name. Nor extension.

Comment: `insert(strBuilder.length()`??? Where would that be inserted? Why do t you just use append()? This inserting makes code unreadable.

Comment: `in a file explorer app`. Which one? Did you try other file explorer apps?

Comment: It is a strange story as also a html file of 0 bytes size should be opened in a html viewer. I just tried that and it does.

Comment: The path is not fixed, but an argument that user sets, hence I indicated which particular path when testing, in previous comment. File explorer app installed in particular is called File Manager. I will look into others. But doubting since the issue doesn't persist after file transfer, this rather seems to show something with initial file isn't well defined. I don't know if file system related or file writing issue.

Comment: Is the file size different after the pc voyage? Do you put the file back in the same directory?

Comment: `The path is not fixed, but an argument that user sets,`. That does not matter. You should supply complete code which we just have to copy/paste to test.

Comment: File name is also a user argument, but it's just "test" and extension is ".html", since you mentioned. All appears correct in created file.

Comment: Again: supply code that we only have to copy/paste. User argument are the last we wanna see.

Comment: About file size, it remains the same after voyage. With above path, name and extension info it's rather clear and trivial to test, not much different from copy pasting. That will be the most I can do but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this before your HTML Tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and delete the StringBuilder.append("test");

Comment: Thanks, just tried this but result is still the same. Actually, instead of "test" I need to append some user edited string content. But to see if the issue was there, I just replaced with that line. Then wrapping with html header and footer, at least that's the idea if something isn't wrong there.